# mongodb "distinct" query?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am not sure whether "distinct" is the right word for this.

I have a simple messaging system in mongo with "sender","receiver","content".

The problem I have is in the inbox page: say for example I have 3 messages from John and 4 from Jack, I would like to show in my inbox only the last message sent by each of those people.

I have searched online and I *thought* this http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct would be the right thing but, it doesn't seem to work or atlest I can't get it to work... meh..

Comment: what do you mean conversion like ??? Like gmail inbox ?

Comment: yes, well.. the conversation part is not very related. but yes pretty much like gmail, facebook or any other messaging system. i don't really want them grouped, as this would be a harder work. i just want only the last message send by someone to be displayed in the inbox page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ciao Enrico,

I didn't really get your question, so I'll try to explain how distinct works:

```
Collection name: foo

Doc no.1: {'a':1,...}
Doc no.2: {'a':2,...}
Doc no.3: {'a':3,...}
```

If then you run:

```
db.runCommand( { distinct: 'foo', key: 'a' } )
```

What you'll get will be:

```
[1,2,3]
```

And I don't think that will be of any use to you. Instead try sorting by date sent and limiting the results to one:

```
db.collection.find(<your_filters_here>).sort({<date_sent_key> : -1}).limit(1)
```

Comment: i'm not sure that would work, if i limit the result by one, it will only give one result. that can work if in my inbox i am talking only to ONE person... but there are other people's messages as well

Comment: Oh I see, you need the first message from all the senders. Then it's a map/reduce job. (You'll need to map every message with key: sender and reduce them in order to take only the most recent message).

Comment: i just found out an easier way! everytime a new message is sent, mark it with a "isLast:1", and as new messages are written, set the old ones as isLast:0... simple as that!